# given a valid href, what are regx for origin, pathname, search and hash?

Tags: javascript, regex, href, location-href

in `javascript`, given a valid `url`, eg,

`http://seeplai2.trailsandtribulations.nat/admin/items?var=val#here`

what are expressions to extract the origin, pathname, search and hash as found in `window.location`?

being relatively weak in `regx`, here are my guesses:

```
origin: href.match(/(.*?)(\/|\?|#))[1]

pathname: href.match(\/\/[^\/]*([^\?#]*)/)[1]

search: (href.indexOf('?')>-1) ? href.match(/\?[^#]*)/)[1] : ''

hash: (href.indexOf('#')>-1) ? href.match(/(#.*)/)[1] : ''
```

do these look right?

here's the sample code:

```
<a href='/path?var=val1' onclick='doClick(event)'>Anchor1</a>

function doClick(e) {

  var href = e.target.href;
  var origin = href.match(/regx/)[1];

  // if different origin, go there
  if( origin != window.location.origin ) return;

  // if only hash difference, let default take over
  ...

  // if path different, process here
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why not use hostname, search, hash and pathname from the location object?

Comment: @mplungjan I am trapping `anchor` click events and processing them.  I need to compare the `anchor.href` to the `window.location` to know how to handle them correctly

Answer (score 1):

Why use regexp?

```
var link = document.createElement("a")
link.setAttribute("href","http://seeplai2.trailsandtribulations.nat/admin/items?var=val#here");
alert(link.search)
```

to compare origin, use the more compatible

```
location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname
```

for example

```
window.onload=function() {
  var winOrigin = location.protocol+"//"+location.hostname;
  var links = document.links;
  for (var i=0,n=links.length;i<n;i++) {
    links[i].onclick=function() {
      var linkOrigin = this.protocol + "//" + this.hostname;
      alert(winOrigin===linkOrigin);
    }
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6vGfB/);

Comment: I think we're missing each other.  I have a valid anchor which has a valid href.  When user clicks the anchor I wish to extract the origin etc so I can compare those to the `window.location.origin` etc so I can know how I wish to process the link.